# AVCaptureDevice's exposureDuration and iso not honored by AVCapturePhotoOutput

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

Problem: use `AVCaptureDevice.setExposureModeCustom` to set a fast "shutter speed" (exposureDuration) and high ISO, call `AVCapturePhotoOutput` to take a photo, see in the resulting image that the exposureDuration / ISO are not used (even though the live video feed shows that it is using the duration/ISO by brightening/darkening as expected)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that `AVCapturePhotoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled` is to blame: by default this is true, and when true **your exposure duration and ISO setting can be ignored / reset**.

Solution is to set this to false when you're using a custom exposure setting, like this:

```
        // self.customDuration is nil if we're on auto-exposure, non-nil if we are on manual exposure, ie. we called AVCaptureDevice.setExposureModeCustom
        let photoSettings: AVCapturePhotoSettings
        if self.photoOutput.availablePhotoCodecTypes.contains(.hevc), heicSupported {
            photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format:
                [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.hevc])
        } else {
            photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format:
                [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
        }
        // auto still image stabilization destroys our settings for custom exposure (iso, duration), so turn it off if we have any
        photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = self.customDuration == nil ?
            self.photoOutput.isStillImageStabilizationSupported : false
```

Comment: `isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled` was deprecated in iOS 13.0, but it still causes custom exposure false. Do you know how make custom exposure works without this setting?